# Metric Spaces And Covering Theorems

Tags: analysis, solution-verification

Prove that a metric space with the property that any infinite susbset has a limit point in it is compact.
$$$$Please Check The Proof:
$$$$I will use the Theorem that for any collection of countable open sets that cover a compact metric space there is always a finite subcover.
$$$$Let $X$ be a metric space with the above property. Now let $\delta>0$ be given. Chose $x_1 \in X$. Now chose $x_2 \in X$ such that $$d(x_1, x_2) \geq \delta$$. Similarly chose $x_3 \in X$ such that $$d(x_1, x_3) \geq \delta; d(x_2, x_3) \geq \delta$$. Proceeding in the similar manner we chose $x_j \in X$ such that $$d(x_i,  x_j) \geq \delta$$ for all $$1 \leq i \leq j-1$$. We claim that this process should after a finite number of times, suppose it does not, then we find a sequence $x_n$ with the property that if there is any given $m$, for every $n < m$ we have $$d(x_m, x_n) \geq \delta$$. Now according to the given property of the metric space this sequence must have some limit point say $p$, and hence we can find a subsequence of this sequence say $p_n$ that converges to $p$. But as every converging sequence is a Cauchy's sequence and hence $p_n$ is a Cauchy's sequence and hence we can make $d(p_m, p_n)$ as small as we want by making $m, n$ sufficiently larger. But as $p_n$ is a subsequence of $x_n$ so for every $N$ we can find $m, n \geq N$ such that $$d(p_m, p_n) \geq \delta$$ because of the above assumed property. So for every $\delta > 0$ the above explained process must stop after some finite number of steps. So if $\delta$ is given then there exists a $m$ such that for every $x \in X$ there exists some $x_j \in X$ with $1 \leq j \leq m$ such that $$d(x, x_j) < \delta$$. Now consider the set $$E_n = (x_1, x_2, x_3, ....., x_k)$$ with the property that for every $x \in X$ there is some $x_j \in E_n$ such that $$d(x, x_j) < \frac{1}{n}$$ and all $x_j$ lies in $X$, and hence the union $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}E_n$$ is a countable set. So we can arrange it in the form of a sequence say $$(q_1, q_2, q_3, q_4,..........)$$,all the $q_j$ lying in $X$. Now we show that this is a countable dense subset of $X$. Now for every $x \in X$, if $x = q_j$ for some $j$, then we are done and if not then consider any open n-ball centred at
$x$ say $B(x, r)$, with radius $r$. Now chose a $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < r$, so for this $n$ there exists some $q_k$ such that $$d(x, q_k) < \frac{1}{n}$$ and hence $$q_k \in B(x, r)$$, and hence every point in $X$ is an adherent point of $E$ and hence the set $E$ is a countable dense subset of $X$ and hence $X$ is separable and hence Lindelof's Covering theorem can be applied here. And hence for any open Covering of $X$ there is a countable subcover and from the Theorem above we can get a finite subcover of the metric space $X$.
$$$$Is My Proof Correct??

Comment: "I will use the Theorem that for any collection of countable open sets that cover a metric space there is always a finite subcover"  This is not a theorem, as it is not true.  Consider a countably infinite discrete metric space $X=\{x_1,x_2,\ldots\}$, with the countable open cover $\{\{x_1\},\{x_2\},\ldots,\}$.

Comment: For reference purposes, this property is called [Bolzano-Weierstrass compactness](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Bolzano-Weierstrass+compact%22).

Comment: @Aweygan Oh sorry I forgot to write compact metric spaces. With compact metric spaces is the proof Correct??